# jasmine can't access angularjs 1.5 controller property

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd

I'm trying to access the controller's properties in the jasmine tests but I'm having issues setting the test up.

Here's the controller:

```
  adminApp.controller('AdminClientController', [function() {
     var adminClient = this;
     adminClient.name = 'Client Name';
     adminClient.sites = [
     {
        id: "site1",
        domain: "myschool.com",
        pages: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "HOME"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "FORM"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]

  }]);
```

Here is the spec:

```
  describe('AdminClientController', function() {
     beforeEach(module('adminClientApp'));

     var $scope, $controller;

     beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $controller = _$controller_;

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
     }));

     describe('site pages', function() {

     beforeEach(function() {
        //$scope = {};
        controller = $controller('AdminClientController as adminClient', { 
            $scope: $scope });
    });

    it('should create a site model with 2 pages', function() {
        expect(controller.adminClient.sites[0].pages.length).toBe(2);
    });
  });

 });
```

The error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'sites' of undefined
```

Previously I tried initializing the $scope (even though I'm not explicitly using it in the controller) and didn't use the contoller as syntax.

```
  beforeEach(function() {
        $scope = {
            adminClient: {
                sites: [
                    {
                        id: "site1",
                        domain: "myschool.com",
                        pages: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                name: "HOME"
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                name: "FORM"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        controller = $controller('AdminClientController', { 
            $scope: $scope });
    });
```

I'm just starting out with the testing and want to use it early on or else it won't happen later. The other SO questions I found didn't help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not passing in scope to your controller so you don't need it. Try this: controller = $controller('AdminClientController', {}); and refer to it like this: controller.sites[0].pages.length

Comment: Thank you @ScottL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the controller property you're not able to access in your test cases. It's the `adminClient` in `controller` that you're not able to access. And that's because it does not exist.

The place where you've specified

```
expect(controller.adminClient.sites[0].pages.length).toBe(2);
```

You should be specifying

```
expect(controller.sites[0].pages.length).toBe(2);
```

As your `controller` is what is acting as a ref to your `AdminClientController` in this case. While where you've defined `AdminClientController`, `adminClient` is acting as a ref to `AdminClientController`

Also as @ScottL mentioned, since you're not injecting $scope into your controller as a dependency, you don't need it in your test case either.

So this should be you new test case:

```
describe('AdminClientController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('adminClientApp'));
    var $controller, controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
        controller = $controller('AdminClientController', { });
    }));

    describe('site pages', function() {
        it('should create a site model with 2 pages', function() {
            expect(controller.sites[0].pages.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you @Siddarth_Ajmera! I thought the js object would be returned as defined in the controller (.controller('AdminClientController', [function() {
    var adminClient = this;) Basic misunderstanding for me. Much appreciated!